# cordova-plugin-globalization Unable to download plugin

Tags: apache-cordova, plugin

Estou tentando instalar o plugin Globalization em meu projeto usando Cordova e ao tentar adicionar recebo o seguinte erro:

> Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888

O output da instalação detalha os passos:

> You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova telemetry on.
>   No scripts found for hook "before_plugin_add".
>   No version specified for cordova-plugin-globalization, retrieving version from config.xml
>   No version for cordova-plugin-globalization saved in config.xml
>   Attempting to use npm info for cordova-plugin-globalization to choose a compatible release
>   Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888

Log da instalação via linha de comando:

> 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
>   1 verbose cli [ 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External\Node.exe',
>   1 verbose cli   'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js',
>   1 verbose cli   'install',
>   1 verbose cli   '-g',
>   1 verbose cli   'cordova@6.3.1' ]
>   2 info using npm@3.3.4
>   3 info using node@v5.4.1
>   4 silly loadCurrentTree Starting
>   5 silly install loadCurrentTree
>   6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
>   7 silly fetchPackageMetaData cordova@6.3.1
>   8 silly fetchNamedPackageData cordova
>   9 silly mapToRegistry name cordova
>   10 silly mapToRegistry using default registry
>   11 silly mapToRegistry registry registry.npmjs.org
>   12 silly mapToRegistry uri registry.npmjs.org/cordova
>   13 verbose request uri registry.npmjs.org/cordova
>   14 verbose request no auth needed
>   15 info attempt registry request try #1 at 4:27:15 PM
>   16 verbose request id 629be16c7e09b198
>   17 http request GET registry.npmjs.org/cordova
>   18 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
>   19 info attempt registry request try #2 at 4:27:26 PM
>   20 http request GET registry.npmjs.org/cordova
>   21 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
>   22 info attempt registry request try #3 at 4:28:27 PM
>   23 http request GET registry.npmjs.org/cordova
>   24 silly fetchPackageMetaData Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
>   24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:176:17)
>   24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:260:16)
>   24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>   24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
>   24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:262:9)
>   24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>   24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
>   24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1255:8)
>   24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:474:9)
>   24 silly fetchPackageMetaData     at process._tickCallback (node.js:388:17)
>   24 silly fetchPackageMetaData  error for cordova@6.3.1 { [Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888] code: 'ECONNRESET' }
>   25 silly rollbackFailedOptional Starting
>   26 silly rollbackFailedOptional Finishing
>   27 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Starting
>   28 silly runTopLevelLifecycles Finishing
>   29 silly install printInstalled
>   30 verbose stack Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
>   30 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.onError (C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External\node_modules\request\node_modules\tunnel-agent\index.js:176:17)
>   30 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:260:16)
>   30 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>   30 verbose stack     at ClientRequest.emit (events.js:169:7)
>   30 verbose stack     at Socket.socketErrorListener (_http_client.js:262:9)
>   30 verbose stack     at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
>   30 verbose stack     at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
>   30 verbose stack     at emitErrorNT (net.js:1255:8)
>   30 verbose stack     at nextTickCallbackWith2Args (node.js:474:9)
>   30 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (node.js:388:17)
>   31 verbose cwd C:\projects\KnockOut\KnockOutApp
>   32 error Windows_NT 6.1.7601
>   33 error argv "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External\Node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Web\External\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova@6.3.1"
>   34 error node v5.4.1
>   35 error npm  v3.3.4
>   36 error code ECONNRESET
>   37 error network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:8888
>   37 error network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
>   37 error network and is related to network connectivity.
>   37 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
>   37 error network
>   37 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
>   37 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>   38 verbose exit [ 1, true ]

Comment: Qual comando você está usando para tentar instalar o plugin?

Comment: Talvez você deva tentar instalar pela linha de comando com `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-globalization`.

Comment: Desculpe, é que eu não uso o Visual Studio. Eu costumo gerenciar o projeto Cordova no qual trabalho pelo terminal do Linux.

Comment: Descobri como faz a instalação por linha de comando e está acusando o mesmo erro. Pode parecer que é um erro de conexão por proxy, mas outros plugins foram instalados semana passada e não tive problemas.  

Veja o log detalhado na descrição do erro que editei.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segui as orientações da segunda opção mais votada dessa pergunta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18419144/npm-not-working-read-econnreset e resolvi meu problema.

Não sei o porquê de um proxy estar configurado para o npm usar e simplesmente removi as configurações de proxy usando 3 linhas de comandos:

```
npm config get proxy
npm config rm proxy
npm config rm https-proxy
```

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente é um erro de proxy, faça um teste. Tente rotear a internet do seu celular e realizar o download.

Alem disso faça pela linha de comando:

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-globalization
```